# partitioning hard disk for dual boot

Tags: partitioning

I have a 500 GB hard disk and I intend to dual boot it with Windows and Ubuntu. I want to reserve about 150 GB for Windows and the rest of the 350 GB for Ubuntu.

1) Is the entire 350 GB is going to get used for file system?

2) Can I create partitions in Linux like it can be done in Windows? Eg: C: D: etc..

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that. Create an extended partition and then logicals within that.

They won't be called d, e, f etc though.

When you install you do so to the / mountpoint, if you only want to have a 16Gb (for example) system partition then do so.

You can then create your other partitions and get them to be mounted within the system using fstab.

If you want to share data between linux and windows - have an ntfs partition.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Answer (score 2):

Well,

Firstly the Linux directory structure *does not* work like windows.

There are **NO** drives by default.The OS and the other things all come under one directory-**ROOT** represented by **"/ "**

Here is how the Linux Directory Structure is-

[image]

The **/Home** is similar to your *My Documents+My Computer*

Well,Though the structure is not *Drive*-based,like windows,you can create partitions(drives) similar to windows(But they wont be named C: or D:...You may label them as seen in the screenshot below or they will be named New Volume1/2/3etc).They are treated as an external media(somewhat like a usb).In linux,anything other than the what is under **"/ "** by default is an outsider(and so are the partitions/drives).

Here is how the drives will look if you hve them-

[image]

The **Devices** part you see in the upper left corner are the drives(the `Eject` arrow shows how they are treated or considered as external devices).

While what you see in the remaining browser is the **/Home"** directory.